# How query linq lambda "where getdate()-Ngaynhap< 15"

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have problem with that query:

```
    select SanPham.*,TenSX  
    from SanPham join NhaSanXuat on SanPham.MaSX = NhaSanXuat.MaSX 
    where GETDATE()- NgayNhap < 15
    order by NgayNhap,MaSP desc
```

I seem to have a problem with : `where getdate() - Ngaynhap < 15`

This  is the linq query :

```
var sp = db.SanPhams.Join(db.NhaSanXuats, masp => masp.MaSX, mansx => mansx.MaSX, 
(masp, mansx) => new { SanPham = masp, NhaSanXuat = mansx })
.Where(ngaynhap=>DateTime.Now.Day - db.SanPhams.Select(n=>n.NgayNhap.Value.Day))
.OrderByDescending(nhap => nhap.SanPham.NgayNhap)
.ThenByDescending(masp => masp.SanPham.MaSP)
.Select(s => s.SanPham);
```

Comment: How can we help when you haven't explained the problem? You haven't said what's going wrong.

Comment: It seems he is asking how to convert the first query into the second one and he is having trouble with the where clause.

Comment: i have trouble with the where clause, how write if((datetime.now- db.sanpham.ngay)<15)

Comment: sorry i write english very bad, I wish you understood 12 years

Comment: What type is NgayNhap?

Comment: NgayNhap define DayImportProduct, NgayNhap pick to nhap.SanPham.NgayNhap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without slightly more information it would be hard to help you better. But I think you are looking for the following:

```
var sp = db.SanPhams.Join(db.NhaSanXuats, masp => masp.MaSX, mansx => mansx.MaSX, 
(masp, mansx) => new { SanPham = masp, NhaSanXuat = mansx })
.Where(db => (DateTime.Now - db.SanPham.NgayNhap).Days < 15)
.OrderByDescending(nhap => nhap.SanPham.NgayNhap)
.ThenByDescending(masp => masp.SanPham.MaSP)
.Select(s => s.SanPham);
```

Comment: `QLMobileDataContext db = new QLMobileDataContext();`

Comment: i have error Error"  'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,bool>)' has some invalid argument"

Comment: If you are using Entity Framework then you shouldn't need to join. And I actually asked what type is NgayNhap which i am currently assuming is `System.DateTime`

Comment: I just did a small test and it worked fine with standard types so you definitely need to check what the type of your property is.